# Accurate implementation of the logarithm of the incomplete Beta function in C++?

Tags: numerical-analysis, c++, c

I need an accurate implementation (for use in C/C++) of the logarithm of the incomplete Beta function:

$$\log \mathrm{B}(x,y;\alpha,\beta) = \log \int_x^y t^{\alpha-1}(1-t)^{\beta-1}\mathrm{d}t$$

with domain $\alpha,\beta>0$, $0\le x\le y \le 1$. I need this to avoid overflows with very large values of the incomplete Beta function.

Boost and GSL provide direct implementations of $\mathrm{B}(x,y;\alpha,\beta)$ or its regularized version. This won't work for me, because from these there's no way to get the value of $\log \mathrm{B}(x,y;\alpha,\beta)$ without going through the large values I am trying to avoid (or at least I don't know how).

Any advice?

**Update:**  I found that `R` has an implementation of the logarithm of the incomplete Beta function (see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Beta.html). Can I use this from C++? Will it be as fast as native C code?

Comment: Have you seen [this question/answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514955/numerical-approximation-for-log-of-incomplete-beta-function) for the "lower" incomplete beta function, $B(0,y;a,b)$?

Comment: +1 @horchler Thanks. Any idea of how I can use that to get the logarithm of general incomplete beta function?

Comment: Have you tried $\ln B(x,y;\alpha,\beta) = \ln B(0,y;\alpha,\beta) - \ln B(0,x;\alpha,\beta) = \ln \frac{B(0,y;\alpha,\beta)}{B(0,x;\alpha,\beta)}$? Or are the numerics not good (e.g., catastrophic cancellation)?

Comment: @horchler Your equation is not correct. The correct equation is $\mathrm{B}(x,y;\alpha,\beta) = \mathrm{B}(y;\alpha,\beta) - \mathrm{B}(x;\alpha,\beta)$, without logarithms.

Answer (score 3):

Boost provides all the functions you need, so it should be sufficient. Instead of using the direct integral representation of the incomplete beta function, it's better to use the *regularized incomplete beta function* (see [DLMF 8.17](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17)):
$$ B(x,y;a,b) = (I_y(a,b)-I_x(a,b))B(a,b). $$
This way, $I_x(a,b)=B(x;a,b)/B(a,b)$ will have values in $[0,1]$, so that
$$ \log B(x,y;a,b) = \log(I_y(a,b)-I_x(a,b)) + \log B(a,b). $$
is much easier to compute. This way the only source of numerical instability, assuming the underlying functions are stable, would be the subtraction when $x$ and $y$ are very close; in that case, if it ever arises, the direct integral representation might work.

The regularized incomplete beta function is given by [`ibeta` in Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_beta/ibeta_function.html), and the log-Beta function can be calculated using the [log-gamma function `lgamma`, also in Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_gamma/lgamma.html). Boost's implementation of $I_x$ is based on the paper [Algorithm 708: Significant digit computation of the incomplete beta function ratios](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=131766.131776) by Didonato and Morris.